# How can we change google map wapoints marking using ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have working code that marks waypoints on google map. I wanted to change the waypoint marking according to the Ajax response.

Here is my code - http://fiddle.jshell.net/TechmazeSolution/8fgobauz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show an attempt to use the response to update the waypoints. But anyway:

1. in the AJAX request, `$(this)` is the AJAX object and doesn't refer to `$("#calcRoute")`
2. you must call `findroute()` after you update the `waypts` array

**Updated code**:

```
$("#calcRoute").change(function () {

    var self = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-response.php?" + Math.random(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { console.log($(this));

            if (self.val() == 1) {

                start = new google.maps.LatLng(1.30365, 103.85256);
                end = new google.maps.LatLng(1.29411, 103.84631);
                waypts = [{
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(1.28644, 103.84663),
                    stopover: true
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(1.28627, 103.85927),
                    stopover: true
                }];

                findroute();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Updated fiddle**:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8fgobauz/1/

Use your javascript console to debug your code. You could find these errors easily.